# best practices request for np.where() that obviates the double dereferencing of the np.where object

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to evaluate

```
x=np.array([1,2,3])
imax=np.where(x==max(x))
```

Clearly `imax=2` but that is not what `np.where` returns. To obtain `imax=2`, I must use a two-step process that involves doubly dereference the np.where object:

```
np_where_object=np.where(x==max(x))
imax = np_where_object[0][0]
```

But this is inelegant. Is there a best practice that avoids the double dereferencing and obtains `imax=2` in one pass? And I don't mean `np.where(x==max(x))[0][0]`, which is still inelegant.

Comment: @richardec, that doesn't work.  `np.nonzero` returns a tuple, not a 2d array.

Comment: Understanding what `np.nonzero` returns is more elegant than some clever work around.  The first `[0]` returns the index array for the first dimension.  The second `[0]` returns the first index of that array.  In the more general case, `x` may be n-dimensional, with duplicate values.

Comment: `np.argwhere` returns the `transpose` of the `np.nonzero` result.  In your case that will be a (1,1) array.  `np.argwhere(x==max(x)).item()` can return that 1 value - for a 1d array with a single max value.

Comment: This is not an answer but the documentation says:
`When only condition is provided, np.where function is a shorthand for np.asarray(condition).nonzero(). Using nonzero directly should be preferred, as it behaves correctly for subclasses.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's [`argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> imax = x.argmax()
>>> imax
2
```

Comment: This won't do the same as `where` as only the **first** max value will be returned

Comment: Is that not what the OP is expecting?

Comment: Yes, thank you. ```np.argmax()``` is the obvious choice. Sadly, it is not to be found in the ```np.where()``` documentation as a credible alternative for the simpler cases. When multiple maxima are involved, then ```np.where()[0][0]``` and ```np.argmax()``` appear to behave the same, choosing the first case only.

Comment: @PeterLeopold Maybe they didn't put in the docs because `np.where(x == max(x))` is to pass the data at least twice and therefore not a use case for `np.where`. OTOH, searching as *maximum index numpy* on a search engine with my bad English gives promising results right away.